# Copy List<BaseList> to List<DerivedList> with override properties c#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have two classes, one of them is derived from other.

```
public class BaseClass
{
    private int iD;
    private string name;
    private int typeID;

    public int ID { get => iD; set => iD = value; }
    public string Name { get => name; set => name = value; }
    public virtual int TypeID { get => typeID; set => typeID = value; }
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    private int typeID;
    private string typeName;
    private Types types; // This is a list of some other objects to lookup;

    public DerivedClass(Types types)
    {
        this.types = types;
    }

    public override int TypeID
    {
        get => typeID;
        set
        {
            typeID = value;
            typeName = types.Where(o => o.ID == value).FirstOrDefault().Name;
        }
    }
    public string TypeName { get => typeName; }
}
public class Type
{
    public int ID;
    public string Name;
}
public class Types : List<Type> { };

List<BaseClass> baseClassList = new List<BaseClass>();
baseClassList.Add(new BaseClass() {ID = 1, Name = "aaa", TypeID = 1});
baseClassList.Add(new BaseClass() { ID = 2, Name = "bbb", TypeID = 1 });

Types typeList = new Types();
typeList.Add(new Type() { ID = 1, Name = "LookupName" });
```

Is it possible to copy List of `BaseClass` to List of `DerivedClass` without enumerating all objects in list (I mean without using `foreach` clause)?

Added some code to create objects.

Comment: "without enumerating all objects in list?" - no

Comment: Your list only has instances of `BaseClass` in it.  Attempting to cast those to `DerivedClass` will fail because they're not instances of `DerivedClass`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure all list members are of type `DerivedClass` you can try `Cast` method of list:

```
List<BaseClass> baseList = new List<BaseClass>();

//Add some DerivedClass
baseList.Add(new DerivedClass());
baseList.Add(new DerivedClass());

List<DerivedClass> derivedList = baseList.Cast<DerivedClass>().ToList();
```

**EDIT:** if your list items are of type `BaseClass` then you cannot cast them but you may convert them to `DerivedClass` this way:

Create a contructor for `DerivedClass` that accepts a `BaseClass`

```
public DerivedClass(BaseClass baseClass)
{
    this.typeID = baseClass.TypeID;

    this.typeName = baseClass.Name;

    //and ...
}
```

Then:

```
List<BaseClass> baseList = new List<BaseClass>();

//Add some DerivedClass
baseList.Add(new BaseClass()); 

List<DerivedClass> derivedList = baseList.Select(i => new DerivedClass(i)).ToList();
```

Comment: It could be better to use `OfType<T>()` instead of `Cast<T>()`, as this will also deal with situations where not all list members are of the DerivedClass type; unless the possible exception-throwing of Cast<T>() is desired in the application scenario...

Comment: @elgonzo yes if we want to get those `DerivedClass` from the list, `OfType` is a better solution but what if we expect all elements be `DerivedClass`? In this case maybe we want to be notified (with exception) that whether any element is not `DerivedClass`.

Comment: Cast, or OfType, or ConvertAll don't work on this case, because one type cannot be converted to other directly.

Comment: We have overridden property here. And new constructor requires a parameter.

Comment: @kord Can you show us how you are creating your `BaseList` and what already you have tried with `foreach`?